# Django admin page with summer note editor causing toggle to expand making it look odd

Tags: django, summernote

I currently installed django summer note on a blog.  It loads fine, and I see no errors in console, but it looks like this ..

[image]

The main admin loads fine, it's just the create post page.

My admin.py file in the blog looks like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Newsletter

from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin

class PostAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'status', 'created_on')
    list_filter = ('status', 'created_on')
    search_fields = ['title', 'content']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}

    summernote_fields = ('content',)

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)

class NewsletterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'confirmed')

admin.site.register(Newsletter, NewsletterAdmin)
```

And the post models are

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

STATUS = (
    (0,"Draft"),
    (1,"Publish")
)


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_posts"
    )
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_on"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.urls import reverse

        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={"slug": str(self.slug)})


class Newsletter(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=200, unique=True)
    conf_num = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email + " (" + ("not " if not self.confirmed else "") + "confirmed)"
```

Comment: share`Post` model code

Comment: @AshishSondagar I have gone ahead and added them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason my admin CSS wasn't fully copied.  So make sure when you collect static that you pass it to the static if you are using nginx correctly.